# Solution to klein-gordon type equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

While studying physics, I ended up having to find solutions for the following partial differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial \alpha ^{2}}-\frac{%
\partial ^{2}}{\partial \phi ^{2}}\right) +e^{6\alpha-\lambda k \phi }\right] \Psi
(\alpha ,\phi )=0
\end{equation}

Where \begin{equation} \psi=R(\alpha, \phi)e^{iS(\alpha ,\phi)} \end{equation}

is a complex function and Vo and lambda are positive constants. The challenge is to find a analytical solution such that \begin{equation} R(0, \phi)=0 \end{equation}

By simply proposing \begin{equation} R(\alpha, \phi)=\alpha f(\phi) \end{equation}

I get something which seems untractable. A hint may be that, upon introducing u,v such that

\begin{equation}
u=\frac{\sqrt[2]{2V_{0}}}{3}\frac{e^{3\alpha -(\lambda \sqrt[2]{6}/2)\phi }}{%
1-(\lambda /\sqrt[2]{6})^{2}}(\cosh (A)+\frac{\lambda }{\sqrt[2]{6}}senh(A))
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
v=\frac{\sqrt[2]{2V_{0}}}{3}\frac{e^{3\alpha -(\lambda \sqrt[2]{6}/2)\phi }}{%
1-(\lambda /\sqrt[2]{6})^{2}}(senh(A)+\frac{\lambda }{\sqrt[2]{6}}\cosh (A))
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
A=3\phi -\frac{\lambda \sqrt[2]{6}}{2}\alpha
\end{equation}
the equation becomes just a klein-gordon equation 
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial u^{2}}-\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial
v^{2}}\right) \Psi (u,v)+\Psi (u,v)=0
\end{equation}

I´ve tried to solve it by imposing an ansatz for R in these new variables but it gets terribly ugly. Could there be any hope?

Comment: It might be a bit late, but: why not Fourier Transform your last equation?